# If I use an nchar column, how can I store Czech text in an IBM819 database?

Tags: .net, vb.net, unicode, informix

I asked a question yesterday, about switching our database over to UTF-8 (multi-byte char, unicode) encoding from IBM819 (single-byte char, [Latin1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) subset), because of a new requirement to support text entry of [Czech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-2) characters.

I've just been reminded by a colleague of the nchar and nvarchar column types, which neither of us has actually ever used.

If I were to define the relevant columns as nchar and nvarchar instead of char and varchar, what would I have to do to allow my currently-IBM819 database to work with this new IBM819-incompatible text coming in from my .net application?

Would all conversion be automatic?

Would I need to write some scary conversion code?

Is this just a nonviable solution and I'm chasing rainbows?

**EDIT:** Right, I defined an "nchartest" table containing a single column, "ntest" of type nchar(500).

I connected to that via .net code and confirmed that 500 chars of [lorem ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com/) could be entered:

```
Dim insertString As String = "INSERT INTO nchartest VALUES (?)"
Dim insertCommand As New IfxCommand(insertString, cConnection, tTransaction)
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("incident_recno", IfxType.NChar).Value = "[lipsum]"
Return insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
```

I then replaced the lipsum string with 100 or so chars of Czech text, and attempting to insert that caused an IfxException to be thrown by the .net Informix interface, with the message `ERROR [HY000] [Informix .NET provider]Unspecified System Error =  -21005.`

Following up on some research I did yesterday, I tried setting my `CLIENT_LOCALE` setting in my connection string to `en_US` to match that reported by `Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`, but that connection could not be opened due to `ERROR [HY000] [Informix .NET provider][Informix]Unable to load locale categories.`

Following that, I tried setting `CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.unicode`, which produced an `ERROR [HY000] [Informix .NET provider][Informix]Unspecified System Error =  -31142.`

Now I'm stumped again.

Comment: The nchar or nvarchar column types are Unicode, so are your .NET strings.  Problem solved.

Comment: Sorry, no. I tried some test code and it didn't work. Just writing up edits to the main question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NATIONAL CHARACTER (N[VAR]CHAR) being interpreted as UTF-16 code units is a trait specific to MS SQL Server. The ANSI SQL standard doesn't specify that behaviour; other databases have different reactions to NCHAR.

Informix uses it to decide whether to use a locale collation instead of a code-unit collation, but it doesn't affect the underlying character set so it doesn't help you here.

You would still have to use a UTF-8 locale either way, and yes, if you've got existing terminal applications using the database then it's very unlikely they're going to be able to cope with Unicode.

Comment: Oh dear. That's pretty much exactly the answer I was hoping I wouldn't get... Right, well, I'm off you go and try to bully our DBA into letting me create a new database using UTF-8, just to store the strings for this application, then. That seems to be the only sane path left open to me.